# C-style Character Strings

Tags: c++, string

In my C++ book, there is a two page section C-Style Character Strings (which almost seems pointless since it tells us twice that C++ programmers shouldn't use C-style character strings), but one thing I'm confused is..what is the difference between:

```
char ca[] = {'C', 'a', 't'};
```

and

```
char ca[] = "cat";
```

For the first one, it says that it might have "disastrous" results because a c-styled string must be null-terminated. But isn't the second one also a c-styled string? How come I don't have to type "cat\0" or something like that? Shouldn't that also lead to "disastrous results"?

Comment: It's not really pointless. Even as a C++ programmer, you'll have to know how C strings work sooner or later. You can use `std::string` all you want, but good luck avoiding ever needing to use a C string.

Comment: "C-style" strings is just a name. They still exist in C++, and you still need to know how to use them, because all the higher-level string stuff is implemented on top of them.

Comment: `\0` is automatically added when you use double quote syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second is equivalent to

```
char ca[] = {'c', 'a', 't', '\0'}
```

Note the terminating `NUL` character, absent in the first example.

You don't have to type `"cat\0"` because the compiler automatically adds a `NUL` character when initializing the array with a string literal. Them's the rules.

Comment: So in the second case, the null character is added automatically. Hmm, yes, I do think the book mentioned that earlier..oops.

Comment: I think the question I meant to ask was: why does the following code work?
const char ca[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
     const char *cp = ca;
     while (*cp) {
         cout << *cp << endl; 
         ++cp;

It was not null terminated, and yet it still prints out the word hello

Comment: @user2782635 You're just lucky. It's undefined behaviour (the moment you dereference `ca+5`, it's UB).

Comment: What do you mean by "works"? This code would print "hello" then random garbage until it just happens to hit a zero byte. Perhaps you would get lucky and there would be a zero byte right after 'o', but don't count on it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik it printed each character in hello in its own line and it didn't print anything else, so I assumed it worked..

Comment: Try this: `const char padding1[] = "garbage"; const char ca[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'}; const char padding2[] = "garbage";` and then your printing code. This arrangement makes it less likely that you end up with a `NUL` byte right after 'o' by accident. I predict your code would print "hellogarbage".

Comment: It actually ended up printing "garbagehellogarbage"...but I think the point you're trying to get at is that undefined behavior basically means that anything can happen, and that your code might look like it works properly (even though it's..not good for it)??

Answer (score 1):

C style strings must be null terminated because many algorithms look for the null.  Things like string copy may never end if they never find a null.

```
char ca[] = "cat";
char ca2[] = {'C', 'a', 't', '\0'};
```

`ca` and `ca2` are identical.  As for why you don't have to type "cat\0" or something like that, its because this is SUCH a common pattern that the language makers defined the meaning of a double-quoted string to include a null implicitly.  Its just a convenience thing

Answer (score 1):

C-style strings are null-terminated, so there is one padding `\0` at the end of the array:

```
char ca[] = "cat";
```

is the same as:

```
char ca[] = {'c', 'a', 't', '\0'};
```

Note again this array has 4 elements.

Answer (score 0):

In C language the syntax

```
"cat"
```

introduces a nameless array object (called *string literal*) consisting of four characters: `'c'`, `'a'`, `'t'` and `'\0'`. That's just how the language is defined. (Just for the sake of experiment, you can print `sizeof("cat")` and see that it is 4, not 3).

So when you write

```
char ca[] = "cat";
```

you are actually defining an array of 4 chars with `'\0'` at the end. Nothing disastrous about it.

The first declaration is not a C string at all. C strings, by definition, are always zero-terminated. If your sequence of characters is not zero-terminated, it is not a string.